# Unknown Parameter Error for Datatable with dynamic columns being displayed

Tags: javascript, datatables

It keeps throwing unknown parameter S.N. on row 0 column 0. This is shown twice and then it exits. The columns are fetched via ajax and so are the data.

The structure is constructed correctly. Checked it with the console.

But this error pops up and the datatables is empty.

The no.of columns are correct tho but without any data.

```
if (response.isOk == true)
    {
        var data = new Array();
        var columns = JSON.parse(response.responseObject.columns);
        var counter = 1;

        $.each(response.responseObject.data, function(index, value)
        {
            var datum = new Array();

            $.each(columns, function(ind, val)
            {
                if (val.data == "S.N.")
                {
                    datum.push(counter);                    
                }
                else 
                {
                    datum.push(value[val.data]);
                }               
            });

            counter++;

            data.push(datum);
        });

        if (tabReport != "")
        {
            tabReport.destroy();
        }

        tabReport = $("#tabReport").DataTable
        (
            {
                dom: "Bfrtip",
                columns: columns,
                buttons: 
                [
                    {
                        extend:    "excelHtml5",
                        text:      'Download',
                        titleAttr: "Excel"
                    }            
                ],              
                data: data
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Please add `console.log( data );` just before `tabReport = $("#tabReport").DataTable...` and include the results of that call here.

Comment: Data

0: (7) [1, "29", "ivws", "2015-05-29 12:08:52", "active", "demo", "GAGAN MAHESHWARI"]
1: (7) [2, "284", "Karmel", "2015-06-26 12:18:00", "inactive", "active", "ADITYA MAHESWARI"]

Comment: Columns

0: {data: "S.N.", mData: "S.N."}
1: {data: "SId", mData: "SId"}
2: {data: "School", mData: "School"}
3: {data: "Created", mData: "Created"}
4: {data: "Status", mData: "Status"}
5: {data: "Lead", mData: "Lead"}
6: {data: "Employee", mData: "Employee"}

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov my apologies. The issue was with the columns array. I had to render it in the form [[data:asd],[data:asd]]

Thank you for your help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`var columns = 
[
[data: "asd"],
[data: "asd"],
[data: "asd"]
];`
```

This is the desired format for the data table.